# Создание приложения для стриминга музыки

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

Задался целью сделать на сайте плеер для проигрывания собственного радио. Подключать готовые модули с разных сайтов неинтересно, хотелось бы разобраться с созданием собственного приложения, которое будет стримить музыку с сервера. К сожалению, знаний по этой части не хватает, в связи с чем вопрос, на чём можно написать подобное приложение. Язык JavaScript.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не ясен. Вы спрашиваете, на чем можно написать похожее приложение, и тут же пишите - язык JS. На JS и пишите. Для стриминга от сервера WebSocket вам в помощь. Дальше разбирайтесь с кодировкой\декодировкой аудио. В принципе, вам больше ничего и не надо будет.

Comment: https://html5book.ru/html5-audio/

Answer (score 2):

Если задались целью создать приложение именно на JavaScript, есть вариант - радиостанция, организованная в обход традиционного подхода к созданию радио онлайн - без традиционного аудиострима, специальной серверной платформы, вещающих программ и многого другого.
В варианте, который я хочу предложить, достаточно обычного сайта на обычном сервере, даже без PHP, а радиовещание в автоматическом режиме отвечает элемент аудио. Может это так же можно назвать имитацией вещания, но результат имеет такой же эффект - на одновременно открытых страницах даже на разных компьютерах в одно и то же время звучит одно и тоже, как при прослушивании радио. Но любом случае реализазии онлайн радио звук всегда берётся из файлов, которые лежат на сервере. Кроме этого в этом примере выводится история раннее прослушанного в недалёком времени. Алгоритм автосоставления плейлиста таков: в течении одного цикла плейлиста композиции воспроизводятся в случайном порядке, но не повторяются.
Перед первым запуском кода нужно будет сделать кое-какую подготовку - прежде всего желательно загрузить все аудиофайлы на сервер. (они могут быть мультимедийными или содержащими рекламу) Так, как тут всё обходится без PHP и библиотек, в сроках с 68 по 70 нужно будет прописать соответственно пути к файлам, названия треков и их длительности в секундах, которые должны иметь точность более, чем в секунду, чем точнее, тем лучше. Этот пример рассчитан на 10 треков, но количество можно изменить.
Кроме этого нужно будет посчитать суммарную длительность треков в плейлисте и записать её в переводе на милисекунды в 75 строке. А так же посчитать, сколько раз плейлист успел бы воспроизвестись с 1 января 1970 г., и записать это число в 73 строке.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Радио</title>
    <style>
    body{
        background: #ccc;
        font-family: arial;
    }
    button{
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 7px;
        background: #033;
        color: white;
    }
    button:hover{
        background: #066;
        color: gold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    hr{
        width: 80%;
    }
    #myhistory{
        width: 50%;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .mytime{
        background: black;
        color: #ccc;
    }
    .now_live{
        background: black;
        color: gold;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #mes1{
        background: #444;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 98%;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #mes2{
        background: #444;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 98%;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body><center><h3>Радио</h3>
<button id=myplay onclick="listen()">Слушать</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="turn_off()">Выключить</button><hr>
<div id=myhistory>
    <span id=mes1> Сейчас в эфире: </span><br><span id=my_time class=mytime> время </span><span id=nowlive class=now_live> тут будет то,что сейчас </span><br><br>
    <span id=mes2> Раньше звучали: <br></span><br>
    <table id=mytable border=0 cellspacing=0></table>
</div>
</center></body>
<script>
var audio = new Audio();
    audioCat = "mp3/", // Путь к папке, где лежат МП3-файлы, если они в отдельной папке
//  audioCat = ""; // В противном случае присваиваем пустую строку
    mp3 = [
        ["track1.mp3", "track2.mp3", "track3.mp3", "track4.mp3", "track5.mp3", "track6.mp3", "track7.mp3", "track8.mp3", "track9.mp3", "track10.mp3"], // Пути к файлам
        ["Исполнитель1 - Трек1", "Исполнитель2 - Трек2", "Исполнитель3 - Трек3", "Исполнитель4 - Трек4", "Исполнитель5 - Трек5", "Исполнитель6 - Трек6", "Исполнитель7 - Трек7", "Исполнитель8 - Трек8", "Исполнитель9 - Трек9", "Исполнитель10 - Трек10"], // Названия
        [376.3232, 338.367275, 187.87585, 187.64075, 221.991775, 529.6244, 133.5047, 223.8597, 265.8839, 270.086] // Длительности треков
    ],
    numTr = mp3[0].length, // Количество треков в плейлисте
    a = 399300, // Количество раз воспроизведения плейлиста с момента 1 января 1970 г. на момент публикации скрипта на сайте - рассчитать самостоятельно и прописать один раз и на постоянно в момент публикации скрипта на сайте
    hst = [[], []], // История раннее прослушанного
    totalDuration = 3859627, // Сумарная длительность в милисекундах всех треков в плейлисте - рассчитать самостоятельно
    mymax = 7; // Максимальное количество треков в истории раннее прослушанного
function getTrack(){ // Получение данных о текущем воспроизводящемся треке, его временной позиции воспроизведения и времени начала воспроизведения
    randArray = []; // Случайные номера треков
    var tek = new Date().getTime();
    var numCycles = Math.floor(tek / totalDuration) + 20; // Количество раз воспроизведения плейлиста с момента 1 января 1970 г.
    var ind = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < numTr + 1; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < numCycles - a; j ++){
            ind ++;
            if(ind == numTr)ind = 0;
            while(randArray[ind]){
                ind ++;
                if(ind == numTr)ind = 0;
            }
        }
        randArray[ind] = i;
    }
    var newCycle = numCycles * totalDuration; // Время начала нового цикла воспроизведения плейлиста
    var mytime = (tek - newCycle)/1000; // Временная позиция воспроизведения всего плейлиста
    var s = 0;
    turn = 0;
    while(s < mytime){
        s += mp3[2][randArray[turn] - 1];
        turn ++;
    }
    turn --;
    index = randArray[turn] - 1; // Индекс (номер) текущего воспроизводимого трека
    var s1 = s - mp3[2][index];
    hour_min = hourmin(newCycle + s1 * 1000);
    curTime = mytime - s1;
}
function listen(){ // Слушаем
    getTrack();
    my_time.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + hour_min + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    nowlive.innerHTML = mp3[1][index];
    audio.src = audioCat + mp3[0][index];
    audio.currentTime = curTime;
    audio.volume = 0.3;
    audio.play();
}
function turn_off(){ // Выключим
    myplay.disabled = true;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        audio.volume -= 0.03;
        if(audio.volume <= 0.02){
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            audio.pause();
            myplay.disabled = false;
        }
    }, 100);
}
audio.onended = function(){ // Переход на следующий трек
    mes2.style.display = "block";
    if(hst[0].length >= mymax){
        hst[0].shift();
        hst[1].shift();
    }
    hst[0].push(hour_min);
    hst[1].push(index);
    mytable.innerHTML = "";
    for(j = 0; j < hst[0].length; j ++){
        var mytr = document.createElement("tr");
            var mytd = document.createElement("td");
                mytd.className = "mytime";
                mytd.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + hst[0][hst[0].length - 1 - j] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            mytr.appendChild(mytd);
            var mytd = document.createElement("td");
                mytd.className = "now_live";
                mytd.innerHTML = mp3[1][hst[1][hst[0].length-1-j]];
            mytr.appendChild(mytd);
        mytable.appendChild(mytr);
    }
    getTrack();
    audio.src = audioCat + mp3[0][index];
    audio.play();
    my_time.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + hourmin() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    nowlive.innerHTML = mp3[1][index];
}
function hourmin(e){
    var newDate = new Date();
    if(e)newDate.setTime(e);
    var ndArray = newDate.toLocaleTimeString().split(":");
    return ndArray[0] + ":" + ndArray[1];
}
getTrack();
my_time.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + hour_min + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
nowlive.innerHTML = mp3[1][index];
</script>
</html>
```